# Complex data transformation

Tags: database, r, reshape

I need to transform following (simplified) dataset, created by following code:

```
structure(list(W1.1 = structure(c(1L, NA, NA), .Names = c("case1", 
"case2", "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), R1.1 = structure(c(1L, 
NA, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", "case3"), .Label = "2", class = "factor"), 
    W1.2 = structure(c(NA, 1L, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", 
    "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), R1.2 = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    W2.1 = structure(c(NA, 1L, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", 
    "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), R2.1 = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    W2.2 = structure(c(1L, NA, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", 
    "case3"), .Label = "2", class = "factor"), R2.2 = structure(c(1L, 
    NA, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    W3.1 = structure(c(1L, NA, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", 
    "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), R3.1 = structure(c(1L, 
    NA, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    W3.2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", 
    "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), R3.2 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, NA), .Names = c("case1", "case2", "case3"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    age = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Names = c("case1", "case2", 
    "case3"), .Label = c("20", "48", "56"), class = "factor"), 
    gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L), .Names = c("case1", "case2", 
    "case3"), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("W1.1", 
"R1.1", "W1.2", "R1.2", "W2.1", "R2.1", "W2.2", "R2.2", "W3.1", 
"R3.1", "W3.2", "R3.2", "age", "gender"), row.names = c(NA, 3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

For the new data I want: 
- a row dedicated to every x.x, with info on the Rx.x value, age and gender.
- only have a row returned when Wx.x was 1. When 2 or NA, I don't need it.

For my example this dataset should look something like this:

```
  incident type Where Reported age gender
1        1  1.1     1        2  56   male
2        2  3.1     1        1  56   male
3        3  3.2     1        1  56   male
4        4  1.2     1        1  20 female
5        5  2.1     1        1  20 female
6        6  3.2     1        1  20 female
```

Note: the "Where" column can even be omitted since it should be a constant vector of 1, and I don't need it for the analysis.

Comment: The `dput` format you have used is preferred, especially for the input data. For the output data, you could just cut & paste the console output into a code chunk (as I did above).  If you like it I think it might be OK to go back and edit your question to remove the `dput()` version of the output data, for brevity ...

Comment: Thanks, that does look better!

Comment: by the way, nice first question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (mostly) a problem to be tackled by `reshape()`. Assuming your original dataset is called "temp":

First, reshape it from a wide format to a long format.

```
temp.long <- reshape(temp, direction = "long",
                     idvar=c("age", "gender"), 
                     varying = which(!names(temp) %in% c("age", "gender")), 
                     sep = "")
temp.long
#               age gender time    W    R
# 56.male.1.1    56   male  1.1    1    2
# 20.female.1.1  20 female  1.1 <NA> <NA>
# 48.male.1.1    48   male  1.1 <NA> <NA>
# 56.male.1.2    56   male  1.2 <NA> <NA>
# 20.female.1.2  20 female  1.2    1    1
# 48.male.1.2    48   male  1.2 <NA> <NA>
# 56.male.2.1    56   male  2.1 <NA> <NA>
# 20.female.2.1  20 female  2.1    1    1
# 48.male.2.1    48   male  2.1 <NA> <NA>
# 56.male.2.2    56   male  2.2    2    1
# 20.female.2.2  20 female  2.2 <NA> <NA>
# 48.male.2.2    48   male  2.2 <NA> <NA>
# 56.male.3.1    56   male  3.1    1    1
# 20.female.3.1  20 female  3.1 <NA> <NA>
# 48.male.3.1    48   male  3.1 <NA> <NA>
# 56.male.3.2    56   male  3.2    1    1
# 20.female.3.2  20 female  3.2    1    1
# 48.male.3.2    48   male  3.2 <NA> <NA>
```

Second, do some cleanup.

```
temp.long <- na.omit(temp.long)
temp.long <- temp.long[-which(temp.long$W == 2), ]
temp.long <- temp.long[order(rev(temp.long$gender), temp.long$time), ]
rownames(temp.long) <- NULL
temp.long$incident <- seq(nrow(temp.long))
temp.long
#   age gender time W R incident
# 1  56   male  1.1 1 2        1
# 2  56   male  3.1 1 1        2
# 3  56   male  3.2 1 1        3
# 4  20 female  1.2 1 1        4
# 5  20 female  2.1 1 1        5
# 6  20 female  3.2 1 1        6
```

You can do further cleanup to change your column names and column order if it's important.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this reply! I'm sure this function is what I am looking for. The only problem is, I thought I might get the logic, and then apply to my real dataset. But I can't figure it out. I think the problem is sep="" that does not apply to the real variable names. These are:

Comment: nr nis WhereTV1 WhereTV2 WhereTV3 WhereTV4 WhereTV5 FysAbu WhereFA1 WhereFA2 WhereFA3 WhereFA4 WhereFA5 ThreatFysAbu WhereTFA1 WhereTFA2 WhereTFA3 WhereTFA4 WhereTFA5 gender diploma nationality RepTV1 RepTV2 RepTV3 RepTV4 RepTV5 RepFA1 RepFA2 RepFA3 RepFA4 RepFA5 RepTFA1 RepTFA2 RepTFA3 RepTFA4 RepTFA5 Age Age_cat

Comment: I recoded to these vars:

 [1] "ID"          "nr"          "nis"         "gender"      "diploma"    
 [6] "nationality" "age"         "age_cat"     "W.TV1"       "W.TV2"      
[11] "W.TV3"       "W.TV4"       "W.TV5"       "W.FA1"       "W.FA2"      
[16] "W.FA3"       "W.FA4"       "W.FA5"       "W.TFA1"      "W.TFA2"     
[21] "W.TFA3"      "W.TFA4"      "W.TFA5"      "R.TV1"       "R.TV2"      
[26] "R.TV3"       "R.TV4"       "R.TV5"       "R.FA1"       "R.FA2"      
[31] "R.FA3"       "R.FA4"       "R.FA5"       "R.TFA1"      "R.TFA2"     
[36] "R.TFA3"      "R.TFA4"      "R.TFA5"

Comment: And applied this function:

subset.long <- reshape(subset,direction="long",idvar=c("Age","Age_cat", "gender", "diploma","nationality","newID","nr","nis"),varying=which(!names(subset) %in% c("Age","Age_cat", "gender", "diploma","nationality","newID","nr","nis")),sep==".")

But it wouldn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Seems to have worked with this:

subset.long <- reshape(subset,direction="long",varying=9:38,sep=".")

Have to check if I got all the data, but it seems to have been solved. Thanks a bunch for putting me on the way!

Comment: @Marlo, Glad to hear it ultimately worked out. The `reshape` function is one of the tougher functions to get your head around, particularly because of the documentation; but once you've figured it out, it's a really useful function. My use of `which(!names(temp...` is just to avoid having to refer to the columns by their index and to say "get everything that is not an ID variable", but this may not be the case for your actual data.

Comment: Yes, I did wonder about 'which(!names(temp...' for a while. Glad I know what that does now.

I checked the data, and it is correct!